# Highcharts Heatmap: how to highlight entire column on hover?

Tags: highcharts

I have the following very simple heatmap: https://jsfiddle.net/fujigoko/yhd8a6ct/

[image]

```
function getPointCategoryName(point, dimension) {
  var series = point.series,
    isY = dimension === 'y',
    axis = series[isY ? 'yAxis' : 'xAxis'];
  return axis.categories[point[isY ? 'y' : 'x']];
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'heatmap',
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 80,
    plotBorderWidth: 1
  },

  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    min: Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1),
    max: Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5),
    labels: {
      align: 'center'
    }
  },

  yAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },

  colorAxis: {
    min: 0,
    minColor: '#FFFFFF',
    maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
  },

  legend: {
    align: 'right',
    layout: 'vertical',
    margin: 0,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 25,
    symbolHeight: 280
  },

  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      return '<b>' + getPointCategoryName(this.point, 'x') + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
        this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + getPointCategoryName(this.point, 'y') + '</b>';
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1), 15],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 2), 30],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 3), 45],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 4), 60],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5), 75],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 2), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1), 0],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 2), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 2), 15],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 2), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 3), 30],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 2), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 4), 45],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 2), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5), 60],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 3), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1), 0],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 3), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 2), 0],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 3), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 3), 15],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 3), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 4), 30],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 3), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5), 45],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 4), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1), 0],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 4), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 2), 0],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 4), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 3), 0],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 4), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 4), 15],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 4), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5), 30],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1), 0],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 2), 0],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 3), 0],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 4), 0],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5), 15],
    ],
    colsize: 24 * 36e5,
    rowsize: 24 * 36e5,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      color: '#000000'
    }
  }]

});
```

When I move the cursor around, by default, it highlights the current cell by making it lighter with a nice fade effect.

Is there a way to highlight in a similar fashion all the cells in the **current column** and to specify the color to be used (e.g., yellow)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by modifying `point.mouseOver` and `point.mouseOut` events:

```
  point: {
    events: {
      mouseOver: function() {
        var point = this,
          chart = point.series.chart,
          allSeries = chart.series,
          x = point.x;
        allSeries.forEach(series => {
          series.points.forEach(point => {
            if (point.x === x) {
              point.update({
                color: 'yellow',
              }, false)
            }
          })
        })
        chart.redraw()
      },
      mouseOut: function() {
        var point = this,
          chart = point.series.chart,
          allSeries = chart.series,
          x = point.x;
        allSeries.forEach(series => {
          series.points.forEach(point => {
            point.update({
              color: '',
            }, false)
          })
        })
        chart.redraw()
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m380jkLd/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events.mouseOver https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update

Comment: that's brilliant, however, I just realized that it completely wipes to information which was contained in the current column. Is there a way to change just one channel of the color? in other words, get the existing RGB value, and make only adjustments on one of the channels so that it's like you overlay a "yellow transparent"layer on top of the existing data? you know what I mean?

Comment: I'm afraid it will be necessary to achieve this in a more hacky way, like writing a function that will be counting the new color based on the current one: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8fL2yqer/

Comment: you are awesome! This is EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!! This hack should be added to the tool documentation :)